# Question about specific product configuration (type, abilities...)

Tags: product-type

I would like to have following (maybe simple, but i don't know):

1. Create a set-product containing simple products.
2. Set-product has no options.
3. Set-product should have inventory shared with simple products.
4. Set-product should have its own price and everything else custom like its a simple product itself.

Can this be done with bundle?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a bundle (you could have tried this quite easily, by the way).

Comment: Sorry for that kind a question. I tried but was not 100% sure if it all will work as expected since I got a lot of time pressure atm. Thats why I just asked for you help! Thank you!

Comment: It's okay; someone else may have the same question and now there's an answer for them too. That's how Stack works!

Answer (score 0):

I good place to read up about what can be achieve with all the different options for bundlöe products in Magento by default is [this pdf from Magento](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/product_configurations_ebook.pdf)

It is slightly old as it was written with Magento CE 1.5 and EE 1.10 but covers what can be done with bundle products and most still stands true today.